# MacOS shm - Unable to get true data size in shm

Tags: macos, shared-memory

When performing shm-related development on MacOS, the searched processes are shown in the following code (verification is indeed correct).

However, there is a new problem that cannot be solved. It is found that when **ftruncat** adjusts the memory size for **shm_fd**, it is allocated according to the multiple of the page size.

But in this case, when the shared memory file is opened by other processes, the actual data size cannot be obtained correctly. The obtained file size is an integer multiple of the page, which will cause an error when appending data.

```
// write     data_size = 12
char *data = "....";
long data_size = 12;

shmFD = shm_open(...);
ftruncate(shmFD, data_size);    // Actually the size actually allocated is not 12, but 4096
shmAddr = (char *)mmap(NULL, data_size, ... , shmFD, 0); 
memcpy(shmAddr, data, data_size);


// read
... 
fstat(shmFD, &sb)
long context_len_in_shm = sb.st_size;

// get wrong shm size ->   context_len_in_shm = 4096
```

Comment: Does `lseek(shmFD, SEEK_END, 0)` give the correct length?

Comment: @KenThomases no, lseek() always return -1. I use lseek on Linux and everything works fine, but it doesn't work on MacOS

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily use the following structure to record data into shm. The first operation before writing or reading is to get the value of the **data_len** field, and then determine the length of the data to be read and written from the back. Hope for a more concise way, just like the use of **lseek()** under Linux.

```
shm mem map :

----shm mem----
struct {
    long data_len;
    data[1];
    data[2];
    ...
    data[data_len];
}
---------------

long *shm_mem = (long *)shmAddr;
long data_size = shm_mem[0];     // Before reading, you need to determine whether the shm file is empty and whether the pointer is valid. It is omitted here.

char *shm_data = (char *)&(shm_mem[1]);
char *buffer = (char *)malloc(data_size);
memcpy(buffer, shm_data, data_size);
```

Comment: If more than one process is going to be accessing the shared memory at the same time, you'll need to use atomic operations (at least) to make sure they do the right thing.